# Image color detection in twitter bot

Tags: r, twitter

I have been creating a twitter bot to post satellite images of random coordinates and I have found that the vast majority are of the ocean, so I would like to somehow make the bot detect that the entire photo is blue and repeat the process. The bot code is available [here](https://github.com/Daniellop1/fewcoordinates).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, what have you tried so far and what problems are you hitting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to employing machine vision to assess the content of the image to determine whether to sample again, you could simply sample from coordinates that are not the ocean! There are many files produced by geographers that have sought to map the boundaries of the world's continents.

For example, [see here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75033/given-lat-and-lon-identify-if-point-over-land-or-ocean-using-r) for code to do so. You'll need to understand projections and other features of Geographic Information Systems if you want to get extremely accurate, but you can get reasonably accurate using the polygons for oceans. If you REALLY wanted to get accurate, you could obtain a set of shapefiles that partition all possible coordinates (rather than a single "world" shapefile) and use the more-detailed mapping that may accompany those more-zoomed-in shapefiles.

Alternatively, you can implement the model [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/water-detection-in-high-resolution-satellite-images-using-the-waterdetect-python-package-7c5a031e3d16), provided in a guide to water detection in satellite imagery using Python.